# buscar una key en un array de objetos

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Tengo un array tal que:

```
[
  {
    423435235: { data: .... }
  },
  {
    6548u9645: { data: .... }
  },
  ...
]
```

Los números son ids dinámicas,
y tengo una función que recibe una `id` y una `{data}`, que debe de:

- Buscar por el array una key determinada
- Si no encuentra un elemento del array que cumple la condición anterior, pushear este elemento a un estado en React.

La función es la siguiente:

```
const setToState = (id, data) => {
    const exist = widgetValues.filter(element => {
      let isOn = null;
      for (let key in element){
        if(element[key] === id){
          isOn = true;
        }
      }
      return isOn ? element : null
    }) 
    if(exist.length === 0){
      setWidgetValues(oldValues => [...oldValues, {[id]: data }])
    }
  }
```

Pero no funciona el filter...  ¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: puedes intentar algo como `let idABuscar = 423435235;
const a = resultado.filter((item)=> {
  return item[idABuscar];


});`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema de usar `.filter()` es que este va a recorrer siempre todos los registros, siendo que con la primer coincidencia debería dejar de buscar, para solucionar eso sería mejor usar `.some()` que va a retornar `true` en la primer coincidencia. Como lo que tenemos que buscar está dentro de un objeto dentro de un array, podemos usar dos `some` anidados, o bien `.some` y `.hasOwnProperty` de manera de asegurarnos la mínima cantidad de iteraciones. Ejemplo:

```js
let widgetValues = [{423435235: { data: "" }},{65489645: { data: "" }}];

const setWidgetValuesF = (id, data) => {
  if(!widgetValues.some(e=>e.hasOwnProperty(id))){
    widgetValues.push({[id]: data });
  }  
}

setWidgetValuesF("no existe", "datos");
console.log(widgetValues);
setWidgetValuesF("423435235", "datos");
console.log(widgetValues);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
const setWidgetValuesF = (id, data) => {
    const exist = widgetValues.filter(element => {
      let isOn = null;
      for (let key in element){
        if(key === id){
          isOn = true;
        }
      }
      return isOn ? element : null
    }) 
    if(exist.length === 0){
      setWidgetValues(oldValues => [...oldValues, {[id]: data} ])
    }
  }
```

He dado con el fallo! muchas gracias @jackNavaRow

Era un fallo humano, estaba buscando mal en el For in, necesitaba buscar por la key, no por el valor!

Comment: ¿cuál era el fallo?, ayudaría mucho expliques que modificaste

Comment: He puesto la solución. En el for in, estaba mirando el valor, no la key, entonces nunca coincidía :/

Comment: por favor esa explicación si la puedes añadir a tu respuesta ayudaría mucho

Comment: Modificado! muchas gracias por las sugerencias :)

Comment: Por favor cuando te sea posible considera marcar tu respuesta como aceptada, de ese modo queda indicado que ya esta solucionada

Comment: @Adrián pero el codigo te quedaria mas complejocomo lo tienes, el metodo [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) espera tener un `true` o un `false` al tu retornar `return element[id]` si el valor no esta retornara undefined que esto seria falso, caso contrario si encuentra el valor y te evitas un for y tmbien un return isOn, aunque de hecho podria ser solo isOn